# How do I initialize hwnd

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a 32 bit game for experience but I have run into a problem
an error keeps popping up saying "Uninitialized variable hwnd used" I understand what it means but I don't
know what to initialize hwnd as. I have tried setting hwnd to render_state.memory but it doesn't like that ether.

( if you try to compile these make sure to set thier configurations in property's to all configurations ,and exclude from build to true on the fist one (the one just below). Also the .cpp file below is the one called render.cpp)

here is the code with the error:

```
#include <Windows.h>

struct Render_State
 {
int 
width, 
hight;

void* memory;
BITMAPINFO bitmap_info;

 };

Render_State render_state;

void render_backround()
{
if (WM_PAINT)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    HWND hwnd;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    unsigned int* pixel = (unsigned int*)render_state.memory;

    for (int y = 0; y < render_state.hight; y++)
       {
    for (int x = 0; x < render_state.width; x++)
        {
            *pixel++ = x * y + x;
        }
       }
    // render
    StretchDIBits(
    hdc,
    0, 
    0, 
    render_state.width,
    render_state.hight, 
    0, 
    0, 
    render_state.width, 
    render_state.hight,
    render_state.memory, 
    &render_state.bitmap_info,
    DIB_RGB_COLORS,SRCCOPY
     ); 
    {
    
    }

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}
}
```

here is the second .cpp file (this is the main program):

```
#include "renderer.cpp"
#include <Windows.h>



bool running = true;




LRESULT CALLBACK windows_callback(
HWND hwnd, 
UINT uMsg, 
WPARAM wParam, 
LPARAM lParam
)
{
LRESULT result = 0;
switch (uMsg)
{
case WM_CLOSE:
case WM_DESTROY:
{
    PostQuitMessage(0);
}
break;
render_backround();
case WM_SIZE:
{
    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
   render_state.width = rect.right - rect.left;
   render_state.hight = rect.bottom - rect.top;
    int size = render_state.width*render_state.hight*sizeof(unsigned int);
    if(render_state.memory)VirtualFree(render_state.memory,0,MEM_RELEASE);     
    render_state.memory=VirtualAlloc(
    0,size,
    MEM_COMMIT|MEM_RESERVE,
    PAGE_READWRITE);
   render_state.bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biSize = 
   sizeof(render_state.bitmap_info.bmiHeader);
   render_state.bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biWidth =render_state.width;
   render_state.bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biHeight =render_state.hight;
   render_state.bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
   render_state.bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
   render_state.bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
}
break;

default:
{
    result = DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
}
return result;
}

  int WinMain(
  HINSTANCE hInstance, 
  HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
  LPSTR lpCmdLine, 
  int nShowCmd
  )
{
//compile window
CHAR clsName[] = "test";
WNDCLASSA window_class = {};
window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
window_class.lpszClassName = clsName;
window_class.lpfnWndProc = windows_callback;
//register clases
ATOM atom = RegisterClassA(&window_class);
if (0 == atom)
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    return 1;
}

// create window
HWND window = CreateWindow(
   clsName,
   "game", 
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, 
    CW_USEDEFAULT, 
    720, 
    360,
    0, 
    0,
    hInstance,
    0
    );
if (NULL == window)
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    return 1;
}
MSG msg;

// Main message loop:
while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
}
```

all help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know much about 32-bit games, but by looking at the code, the variable `hwnd` is not initialized. I believe, you need pass the `HWND` variable you get from `CreateWindow` function to `render_backround()` function.

Comment: the tutorial I'm watching wants me to keep them separate any way I can do that?

Comment: it also doesn't work in create window

Comment: Why "32-bit"? What's the motivation there? This is just generic Windows code, it really doesn't matter 64 vs. 32 apart from a few slight API changes.

Comment: It's worth noting that this technique went out of date when "WinG", late renamed DirectX was introduced...in 1997.

Comment: 32 bit is less complex for developing games and i know its old and that is why i like it.

Comment: The `window_callback` function is given an HWND as a parameter. That is the window receiving the message and presumably the window you want to repaint. Note that your `render_backround();` call is unreachable.

Comment: could you explane what you mean by unreachable

Comment: also if you have an answer please put it in the answer section with the code you used

Comment: i also updated my code so check it out befor you try to debug

Comment: @RaymondChen that could be an answer. the application does not initialize hWnd; it's value is assigned to the application main window by the operating system, and subsequently passed to every wndproc callback.

Comment: Please format your code properly. It's very hard to read when the indention is like that.

Comment: @RaymondChen that was the first thing I tried

Comment: how should i indent it

Comment: If the tutorial you're watching is having the same indention that you have here, then I would run as far away from them as possible. Generally, you try to indent one step for each block. So everything within opening bracket (`{`) and end bracket (`}`) should be indented one step to show that they belong to a block. Someone edited [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65559914/6486738) a bit, so that might help to look at.

Comment: fixed it hopefully

Comment: You need to add @ and a user's name for them to get a notification. Unfortunately, the code is not better. I understand that you want help with your code, but when the code is this messy it becomes hard and tiring to read. I'm not saying you have edit the code, but I think you'll get more and better answers faster if the people can read the code with ease.

Comment: sorry for the messy code I'll try make it cleaner in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information you provide it's impossible to say for sure, but here is my best guess:

1. Change the signature of your `render_backround()` to this: `void render_backround(HWND hwnd)`
2. Remove the line `HWND hwnd;` from that function
3. In your second .cpp file replace this line `render_backround();` with this: `render_backround(hwnd);`
4. As written, the `render_backround(hwnd);` is unreachable. You are missing a `case WM_PAINT:` line in front of it.

I think this is the way to go, because your function `windows_callback` is later on registered as a callback (as the naming suggests). That means Windows will be responsible for passing it sane parameters. Among those parameters there happens to be a `HWND`, just what you need. So, if the set up callback mechanism works at all, we can expect that this `HWND` instance inside of the callback will be the one to work with. So you only need to use that very same instance in your `render_backround` function, hence you have to pass it there rather than have it declare its own one (which leeds to your error).

Comment: btw found a weird glitch if you tap upvote really quick you can upvote twice